# Plant identification - variegated ivy-like

Tags: species-identification, botany

What plant is this? It's in the UK, grown in a pot, and looks like a variegated ivy.

Leaves are about 2 cm in diameter, and the full plant about 50 cm.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer myself, so here it is.

This is Ceropegia linearis ssp. woodii, also known as hearts on a string or hearts entangled.

More information about the plant can be found at https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=5862